# SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified only with my iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error, domexception

My website works fine but I have a problem with my about section in my iPad. I can't open my about page in my ipad only.

I have this error when I click on it:

> SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12: An invalid or illegal string was specified.

This is the concerned line:

```
}, !0), this.options.content.close && document.addEventListener("keydown", this.action, !0), this.options.overlay.close && this.content.element.addEventListener("click", function(t) {
```

Maybe someone can help, I can't understand why I have this error only in iPad.

[image]